# How does Wordpress options gets called?

Tags: wordpress

How does Wordpress store it's options? By calling for each function when it's required or other way. Is it a good practice to use session to store site options? Thanks.

Comment: What kind of _options_ are you talking?

Comment: settings for post per page, maximum upload size, etc. I'm not using wordpress (i have my own litle cms), but i want to know how WP uses the options to improve performance.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the [options API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Options_API) for WordPress, the best practice to storing options would be to use the `add_option()` function, not using sessions as they can be temporary.

WordPress stores it's options in a table called wp_options (or whatever prefix you used during installation).